# What's the difference between 親睦会 and 懇親会?

Tags: meaning, nuances

I was watching [Hello World](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HELLO_WORLD_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB)) on Netflix when I encountered 親睦会. Googling it, I learned that a similar word, 懇親会, exists. I would like to ask if the content of this [article](https://www.cs-orihara.jp/archives/1381.html) is reliable.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to several online articles Google showed to me, people who believe they are different seem to say 懇親会 is more official/formal/serious (like ones held at a hotel after a business conference or a 入社式), while 親睦会 is more casual/private (like 合コン, お花見, etc). I also feel 懇親会 sounds slightly more formal, but perhaps not many people distinguish them seriously in daily life. In my opinion, it's perfectly fine to call a casual izakaya party a 懇親会, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you naruto-san for your quick reply :) In that case, I will put 親睦会 in my active vocabulary list and 懇親会 (being slightly more formal and less useful given my current interaction with native speakers) in my passive vocabulary list.

Comment: @rebuuilt Google Imageの結果にもほとんど差はないですね…「懇親会」の方がほんのちょっとだけスーツの人が多くて会場が豪華な気もしますが、気のせいかも…。